# How can i deploy ios application on user's device without knowing UDID?

Tags: ios

How can I deploy an iOS application on a user's device without knowing its UDID? Or can I add the device to a particular profile programmatically?

Comment: It dont explains the exact need..!! the question is unclear..

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to do one of the following:

A) Get an iOS Enterprise Account and sign your app with its certificate (though it is a breach of the terms of service to distribute this kind of app outside your company)

B) Put your app on the app store.